# How to redirect to original page after node create

Tags: 7, nodes, redirection

I have a link to a create node form from a particular page.  After the user creates the node and saves, I want to redirect the user back to that page (and not to the new node URL).

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  Just add the '?destination=the/url/you/want/to/redirect/to' to the /node/add/your-content-type' link.

Comment: i think in most cases users want a dynamic link which actually includes the original page, instead of having to hardcode the original url in the link.